# SQL - Export data to a new file on remote folder

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a procedure where I will save some data on my Files Server (as an `.csv`).

Something like this:

```
--Note: I need permissions to access "0.0.0.0" address
--Note: I need to create a new file, and not replace an existing one

Select Name, Email From users => save to '\\0.0.0.0\c\userData'
```

I tried this:

```
--Note: "1.1.1.1" is the server where my database is, not sure if its the parameter I should use on ServerName

Exec xp_cmdshell
'bcp " Name, Email From users" queryout "\\0.0.0.0\c\userData" -c -t , -S "1.1.1.1" -T'
```

Got the following errors:
`SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0`; `Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file`

I also saw that you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [FileName.csv]')
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM DatabaseName
```

But it has the downside the file has to exist already.

**Q:** So how can I achieve this? Export data to a file to a different machine with folder specific permissions/credentials (and create a new file, not overwrite it).

Comment: I would use something *else* and pull the data from SQL Server; don't use SQL Server to call the command line, to call BCP, to call itself, and export the data; it's clunky and you have to be a `sysadmin` to run the process. For example, you might choose to make an SSIS package to export the data, and then you can either run it using SQL, or have to scheduled using the Agent.

Comment: @Larnu yeah, I was kinda getting to the conclusion that giving access from sql to another server wouldn't be well designed. Like, giving my "Data Layer" access to another server, in this case I guess you could call it "Application Layer" doesn't seem advisable. I will probably end sending it as and email (this will raise other problems but meh) or make it as a downloadable file on my web-application.